# How to merge dictionaries within a list based on values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a task of preprocessing messy (fake) data. I've managed to go through most of my data and clean it up until this point shown below:

```
[{'birthdate': '1966-07-17', 'name': 'WORDS, MARK M'},
 {'birthdate': '1966-07-17','name': 'WORDS, MARK MY','placeOfBirth': 'WYOMING','ssn': '999999999'},
 {'birthdate': '1966-07-17', 'name': 'WORDS, MARK MY', 'ssn': '999999999'},
 {'birthdate': '1970-01-01', 'placeOfBirth': 'MISSOURI', 'ssn': '999999999'},
 {'birthdate': '1970-01-01','name': 'BOLLIE PRIDE, CHESTER','placeOfBirth': 'INDIANA','ssn': '999999999'},
 {'birthdate': '1966-07-17', 'name': 'WORDS, MARK M', 'ssn': '999999999'}]
```

I want to merge dictionaries pertaining to the same person, which can be difficult to figure out based on the data. Four of these dictionaries are pertaining to MARK WORDS.

1. One issue is that two dictionaries has the middle initial of the name (M) and the other dictionaries have the full middle name (MY).
2. The second issue is that they don't all have all of the keys.

In future iterations of this task, I also don't know which keys might be guaranteed in all of the dictionaries (In this case birthdate is in all 4 dictionaries regarding MARK WORDS). I also want to note that other dictionaries in the list might not pertain to the same individual (e.g. CHESTER BOLLIE PRIDE). I'm just not sure how to go about this in anyway, so any tips or thoughts would be great.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you have already written and what the result is

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: If you have a `WORDS, MARK MY` and `WORDS, MARK MINE`, how will you decide whom a dictionary with `WORDS, MARK M` belongs to?

Comment: @ChrisSc I've gone through stackoverflow looking at different ways to merge dictionaries to help me even try something out, but I find this problem way above me and my skills including anything I could find online. I further explain the complexity of the problem in my next comment answering Pranav's question.

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi, if multiple names match, then the dictionaries would need to use another key/value pair to further eliminate choices such as "birthdate" or "SSN" if that is available. I assume using SSN is the most ideal because it is a unique ID per person, but unfortunately it isn't always available.